# Accord du participe passé avec un sujet masculin et féminin

Tags: accord, participe-passé

Lorsque nous utilisons le masculin et le féminin dans un même sujet, comment pouvons-nous faire l'accord du participe passé ?

Par exemple: laquelle de ces deux phrases est correcte ?

> Les stations de base et les utilisateurs sont équip**és** d'une seule antenne.
>
> Les stations de base et les utilisateurs sont équip**ées** d'une seule antenne.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Le masculin l'emporte dans un tel cas, c'est donc la première phrase qui est correcte:

> Les stations de base et les utilisateurs sont équip**és** d'une seule antenne.

Comment: Le masculin l'emporte toujours! Même si l'on parle d'un homme avec 999 femmes, il faudra quand même dire "*Ils*" pour les réferrer. Attention cependant, si l'on parle des 1000 personnes, alors on dira "*Elles*" puisque le pronom pointe plutôt à "Personnes", et non pas à "1 mâle + 999 femelles".

Answer (score 5):

La règle habituelle demande le masculin, mais l'usage (de mémoire même tel qu'observé par le *Bon Usage*) est un peu plus flottant, certains semblent accorder avec le dernier terme (ce qui dans ton cas ne change rien) ou le terme logiquement plus important quand il domine relativement nettement les autres (ici les deux termes semblent d'importance égale).

Answer (score 2):

Le masculin ne l'emporte pas toujours ! La [règle de proximité](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A8gle_de_proximit%C3%A9), apparue il y a déjà fort longtemps, nous montre que l'inégalité n'est pas une fatalité et qu'on peut tout à fait se passer du principe de "*genre plus noble*".

Comment: Le lien indique clairement que cette règle n'est actuellement pas valide en Français.